# try/except and descision making

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a function which takes different kinds of date_formats as an argument and dispatches it to a function, which is in charge for parsing this format

In other words:

```
def parse_format(date_format):
    # descision making happens here
     try:
         from_timestamp(date_format)
     except:
         pass

     try:
         from_dateformat(date_format)
     except:
         pass

def from_timestamp(format):
    # raise if not in charge

def from_dateformat(format):
    # raise if not in charge

def from_custom_format(format):
    # raise if not in charge
```

Currently, parse_format has multiple try/except blocks. Is this the way to go, or is there a more obvious way to do it? Furthermore, how do I handle the case, where every function call fails?

Comment: It is a decent way to go, as you can keep adding new formats in a modular way.
for your second question, you could raise an exception before falling off theparse_format function.
another approach would be to first "guess" which format the string is, and executing the corresponding function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
class UnrecognizedFormatError(Exception):
    pass

def parse_format(date_format):
    methods = (from_timestamp, from_dateformat)
    for method in methods:
        try:
            return method(date_format)
        except:
            pass
    raise UnrecognizedFormatError
```

But also some key points:

- `except` without a specific exception is bad, because a exception can be thrown from unexpected places, such as running out of memory, or a keyboard interrupt in a script. So please use the `except SomeException as e` form, and use a specific exception type.
- If every function fails, this code will throw a `UnrecognizedFormatError`, allowing the function's user to respond appropriately.

Comment: Good one, that's what i was thinking about, too. Thanks for pointing out not to catch exceptions blindly. I'll pick this one and add a dectorator to every parser function.

Comment: As a side note, you can catch multiple exception types with one `except` block too, if needed: `except (MyExceptionA, MyExceptionB) as e`

Comment: I thought of extracting the try/catch into a function, but your solution is much better: no need for an additional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would look at this as a great place for try/except/else/finally - the else catching your final case where every function call fails, and the 'finally' being run whatever happens in your try/except statements.  If your exceptions are appropriately chosen, then it will pick the right function for you.

Also, I'm guessing that this is a learning exercise, as the activity you're describing would be better done in [`date.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

```
def from_timestamp(format):
    # raise if not in charge

def from_dateformat(format):
    # raise if not in charge

def from_custom_format(format):
    # raise if not in charge

def parse_format(date_format):
    # decision making happens here
    try:
         from_timestamp(date_format)
    except(FirstException):
          from_dateformat(date_format)
    except(SecondException):
         from_custom_format(date_format)
    else: 
        whatever_you_do_if_it_all_goes_wrong()
    finally: 
        thing_that_happens_regardless_of_what's_called()
```

Comment: I think dealing with two exceptions instead of one is not better. After that, the both exceptions should be mentioned in the comments instead of simply stating `# raise if not in charge`. Your code is misaligned.

Comment: I'd say it depends on the situation.  Different exceptions may need different responses, so catching both in the same is less helpful (but still valid).  In the OP example he seemed to be cascading through different functions, so separate Exceptions seem to be the way forward to ensure validity. (Thanks on the formatting, edited to fix.)